# Indemnity v. Restitutionary/Reliance Damages

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales

1. How does "indemnity" differ from "restitutionary/reliance damages"?
2. Why do these four textbooks all still write "indemnity", when the first textbook quoted below advises it's "more accurate to describe it as a personal
   restitutionary claim"?

McKendrick. [*Contract Law: Text, Cases, and Materials* (2018 8 ed)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Contract-Law-Text-Cases-Materials/dp/019880816X/ref=dp_ob_title_bk). p 611.

> ### (e) RESCISSION AND AN ‘INDEMNITY’
>
> A claimant who rescinds a contract may also be able to bring a claim for what is often referred
>   to as an indemnity, **although it is probably more accurate to describe it as a personal
>   restitutionary claim.** In *Whittington v. Seale-Hayne* (1900) 82 LT 49 the plaintiff entered
>   into a lease of a farm which he intended to use for breeding prize poultry. He was induced
>   to enter into the lease by misrepresentations made by the defendant that the premises were
>   in a good state of repair and in a sanitary condition. The premises were not sanitary and
>   the buildings were in a state of disrepair. As a result the plaintiff became ill and many of the
>   birds died. The plaintiff claimed that he was entitled to set aside the lease and recover an
>   indemnity in respect of the losses which he had suffered in the performance of the contract
>   before it was set aside. It was held that he was not entitled to recover an indemnity in respect
>   of the loss of his birds and the illness which he suffered. At the time at which the case
>   was decided damages could only be recovered in respect of a fraudulent misrepresentation

p 612.

> (see p. 596, Section 5) and the plaintiff could not establish that the defendant had made
>   the misrepresentations fraudulently. But the plaintiff was able to recover the rent paid and
>   the cost of the repair work that had been done pursuant to an order issued by the local authority.
>   These obligations were imposed on him by the terms of the lease. The reason for his
>   entitlement to recover these payments was that they had resulted in an enrichment to the
>   defendant (either through the direct payment of rent or by carrying out the work ordered
>   by the local authority) and, when the lease was set aside, the defendant became subject to
>   a restitutionary liability to repay to the plaintiff the value of the benefits which he had received
>   as a result of the plaintiff’s performance of his obligations under the lease. But he was
>   not subject to any wider liability to pay compensation to the plaintiff for the losses which
>   he had suffered.

[Richard](https://www.uclan.ac.uk/staff_profiles/richard-taylor.php) and [Damian](https://www.slaughterandmay.com/who-we-are/partners/damian-taylor/) Taylor. [*Contract Law Directions* (2019 7 ed)](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/contract-law-directions-9780198836599?&lang=en&).  p 185.

> #### Indemnity for expenses incurred under an obligation
>
> An ancillary order which can also be made along with rescission (even for innocent misrepresentation)
>   is the award of an indemnity. This is a monetary award but should not be confused
>   with damages as it is much more limited. It only covers expenditure which the
>   representee was obliged to incur under the terms of the contract which is being rescinded
>   and which has benefited the other party. It is a restitutionary rather than compensatory remedy
>   and is part of the restitution to the starting position which rescission is designed to
>   achieve. If money has been paid directly to the other party then of course it will be returned
>   as part of the remedy of rescission itself; the indemnity is instead concerned with payments
>   made under the contract to third parties. In *Whittington v Seale-Hayne* (1900) the indemnity
>   included money paid out in rates and to do repairs which the tenant was obliged to do under
>   the lease and which benefited the landlord directly, but it did not extend to medical expenses
>   and loss of stock which, although foreseeable, were not incurred under an obligation contained
>   in the lease. (These latter, and other items claimed, would only be recoverable if a right
>   to damages could have been established, which at the time would have meant proving
>   fraud—the increased availability of damages today would mean that the limited right to an
>   indemnity is less commonly relevant.)

Paul Davies. [*JC Smith's The Law of Contract* (2018 2 ed)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Smiths-Law-Contract-Paul-Davies/dp/0198807813/ref=dp_ob_title_bk).  p. 237.

> #### (b) Indemnity
>
> If a contract is rescinded, that means that the contract is wiped out from the start, so it is
>   logically impossible also to recover damages for breach of contract (which assume that the
>   contract was fully performed). However, a representee may be able to rescind a contract
>   and be paid an indemnity to cover expenses which would necessarily have been incurred
>   by the representor anyway. Otherwise, the representor would be unjustly enriched by the
>   representee’s expenditure.51 This is illustrated by *Whittington v Seale-Hayne*.52 The claimants
>   were induced to take a lease of a farm used for breeding prize poultry by the defendant’s
>   misrepresentation that the premises were in a sanitary condition and a good state of repair.
>   The claimants paid various rates and carried out repairs under the covenants in the lease
>   before rescinding the agreement. Farwell J held that they were entitled to an indemnity for
>   such expenses, since they would have had to be paid anyway by whoever had the farm at the
>   time. However, the scope of the indemnity was limited to expenses incurred which benefited
>   the defendant: the claimant received no indemnity for the loss of poultry, nor for lost profits.

[*Anson's Law of Contract* (2016 30 ed)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Ansons-Law-Contract-Jack-Beatson/dp/0198734786/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=ZW82SGPZDB8D0GKSVMV4). p 335.

> The distinction between damages and an indemnity as it works out in practice may
>   be illustrated by the case of *Whittington v Seale-Hayne*,94 where the Court adopted the
>   narrower principle suggested by Bowen LJ:
>
> Poultry farmers had been induced to take a lease by the defendant’s non- fraudulent
>   misrepresentation that the premises were sanitary. This was not the case, and in consequence
>   of the contamination of the water supply, their manager fell ill and the poultry died. They
>   claimed rescission of the lease, and an indemnity to cover the value of the stock, loss of profit
>   on sales, loss of breeding season, medical expenses of the manager, rates, rent, and money
>   spent on outbuildings, etc. They had also been compelled by the local council to renew the
>   drains, and this item, too, was included.
>
> It was held that the poultry farmers were entitled to have the lease rescinded, and to
>   recover what they had spent on rent, rates, and the renewal of the drains, since these
>   were expenses incurred under the covenants in the lease or arising necessarily out of
>   the occupation of the property, and thus ‘obligations created by the contract’. Their
>   claim for payment in respect of the other items of loss was not allowed, since these
>   were damages, there being no obligation to carry on a poultry farm on the leased
>   premises.
>   In practice, an indemnity is a useful remedy only where the misrepresentation is
>   wholly innocent. In cases of fraudulent or negligent misrepresentation the claimant
>   may claim damages on the tort measure, in addition to rescinding the contract.95

Comment: This is not the right site to describe contract law to you.

Comment: @ScottDunnington I'm uncertain what you mean?